# File sync api for objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file-sharing

I am trying to develop an application for file sync on the cloud.I came across the **DropboxSDK** which is fairly simple.I've kept this as an option for my app.I found another one called **Box .Net**, but its a bit complicated.Can anyone let me know what all api's are there similar to **DropboxSDK** which can provide the same functionality.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you hear about [iCloud](http://www.apple.com/icloud/)?

Comment: No problems! Not out until iOS 5 hits the shelves, though like vicvicvic said it'll basically become the standard for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [Cloud App](http://developer.getcloudapp.com/) (might not be functionally equivalent – it's more for sharing files AFAIK).

With iCloud becoming built-in in OS X and iOS soon, however, it's likely to become *the* standard. Don't know how well it will work for legacy users, who don't upgrade to 10.7, though.